# How to automatically bring servers up if AC returns before the fail process completes?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ups

I have the following processes in place for an AC power loss:

```
UPS emails an "On battery" message
UPS sends a power loss shutdown event to the host OS (hyper-V server 2012 R2)
Host OS sends SNMP messages (via UPS software) to all vm servers to shutdown immediately
Host OS shuts down after time delay allowing vm servers to gracefully shutdown
UPS turns off after time delay allowing Host OS to gracefully shut down

When AC is restored, the UPS auto-starts and the host BIOS boots automatically
Host OS then turns on all vm's using Hyper-V auto-start

Each server including the host uses Group Policy to send emails for shutdown/startup
```

The system works exactly as desired, sending emails at each key point.  The entire system wakes properly on AC restoration.

My concern is how to handle this process if it doesn't continue to the end because AC is restored before everything is turned off.  For instance, if the host never shuts down, then Hyper-V will never startup and it won't trigger the vm's to startup.

Are there some best practices/ideas to manage making sure the system restarts automatically in these circumstances?

Comment: I either plan for enough battery runtime or expect to back the battery with a generator solution. UPS shutdown for single hosts is okay, but when you factor in hypervisors, it's not that great.